# getting Error message while trying to install KVM vm from terminal, host machine is ubuntu20.04

Tags: linux, virtualization, linux-kvm

so in the past when i was installing vms in kvm, i was using kvm GUI, but now i want to install virtual machine from terminal, this is what i tried to do:

```
virt-install --network bridge:virbr0 --name testvm1 --os-variant=ubuntu20.04 --ram=2048     --vcpus=1 --disk path=/var/lib/libvirt/images/testvm1-os.qcow2,format=qcow2,bus=virtio,size=5     --graphics none --location=/home/aron/Desktop/os_distros/ubuntu-20.04.1-live-server- amd64.iso     --extra- args="console=tty0 console=ttyS0,115200" --check all=off
```

the error message i would get:

```
Starting install...

ERROR Couldn't find kernel for install tree.

Domain installation does not appear to have been successful.

If it was, you can restart your domain by running:

virsh --connect qemu:///system start testvm1

otherwise, please restart your installation.
```

after trying to solve that problem by replacing "--location" with "--cdrom"

this is the error message i get:

```
ERROR Kernel arguments are only supported with location or kernel installs.
```

now i want to be able to install vms from terminal, so if somebody could help me, i would be really greatfull, thanks in advance

Comment: in --location, you have an extra space

Comment: @zersh ,  it is from copying and pasting. in original command there is no extra space

Comment: replacing "--location" with "--cdrom" and remove --extra-args ?

Comment: @zersh, it works like that. but the console part is crucial, since if i try to install without extra arguments, then when i get to console to install it, it won't work, i only get this, 'Connected to domain testvm1
Escape character is ^]
' and it cannot take any input beside getting out of the console with 'escape carachter, and i need to use console

Comment: @starboy then follow these https://theharpan.blogspot.com/2019/10/menangani-error-kvm-guest-hangs-at-escape-character-is.html